# Reference.child failed: First argument was an invalid path = "/Users/[object Object]/device_token"

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send notification to users using this java-script code i got from a tutorial

```js
'use strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/Notifications/{user_id}/{notifications_id}').onWrite((change, context) => {
 const user_id = change.after.val();
 const notifications = change.after.val();

 console.log('We Have A Notification for :', user_id);

 if (!change.after.val()){
  return console.log("A Notification Has Been Deleted From The Database: ", notifications_id)
 }

 const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/Users/${user_id}/device_token`).once('value');

 return deviceToken.then(result => {

  const token_id = result.val();

  const payload = {
   notification: {
    title: "Friend Request",
    body: "You just got a new friend request",
    icon: "default"
   }
  };
 
  return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload ).then(Response =>{
 
   console.log('this is the notification')
  });
 

 });


});
```

but when it trys to send the notification it returns this error in the firebase functions log. i don't know if firebase has made a change to their doc.
please i really need help getting this code to work

```js
Error: Reference.child failed: First argument was an invalid path = "/Users/[object Object]/device_token". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"
    at validatePathString (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:1612:15)
    at validateRootPathString (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:1623:5)
    at Reference.child (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:13930:17)
    at Database.ref (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:15093:48)
    at exports.sendNotification.functions.database.ref.onWrite (/user_code/index.js:17:39)
    at cloudFunctionNewSignature (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:105:23)
    at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:135:20)
    at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:758:24
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

Comment: What does that `console.log()` code print for the user id?

Comment: it's not showing any error for that yet